Looking for a word or a term similar to Auteur, applicable to app makers
A person who possesses a vision and expertise in both programming and design, capable of producing an app or software that is unique and superior, has a singular, undiluted vision.
There are some well known apps and games made by one person who had a vision and attended with great professionalism and care to all the details, from programming to interaction and visual.
I was going to use "auteur" but then I read that it's used only in reference to certain film directors.

auteur is perfect. It says in a single word what you've said here. It would be an analogical use.  People might disagree with you but they will understand your intended meaning (if they know how auteur has usually been used heretofore).

You'd call it a one-person app if a single person created and developed it. I don't think there's a specific term meaning "unique and superior" in that way. Even "auteur" in film doesn't mean that - you can be an auteur and make a bad film; Tommy Wiseau and Ed Wood were auteurs.

How about 'Appteur'?

While auteur originated in the realm of film directing, it extends to that of any artistic undertaking. Here is the later definition from the OED:

2. A musician or other artist who retains a high degree of independent artistic control over his or her work, from conception to
production or performance. Also: a creative artist whose work is
perceived to reflect a highly individual vision or innovative
approach, or is (self-consciously) presented as such. 1969–
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

It doesn’t seem to be a problem to extend the term to any creative field, including application development. Here’s an example from a New York Times article:

What Apple Has That Google Doesn’t: An Auteur
The Auteur vs. the Committee One person is the Decider for final design choices. Not focus groups. Not data crunchers. Not
committee consensus-builders. The decisions reflect the sensibility of
just one person: Steven P. Jobs, the C.E.O. . . . The company that has
a single arbiter of taste has been producing superior products,
showing that you don’t need multiple teams and dozens or hundreds or
thousands of voices. Source: New York Times—The Auteur vs.
the
Committee

